# Laravel, how to use another controllers to the same folder

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

I have a big doubt building the structure of my application using Laravel because  I want to use two controllers using the same folder, for example, this is my current structure:

Folder structure

```
app/views/dashboard.blade.php
app/views/settings.blade.php
app/views/business/dashboard.blade.php
app/views/business/settings.blade.php
```

Routes.php

```
Route::get('/user/dashboard','HomeController@dashboard');
Route::get('/user/settings','HomeController@settings');

Route::post('/user/login','UserStandardController@login');
Route::post('/user/logout','UserStandardController@logout');

Route::get('/business/dashboard','BusinessController@dashboard');
Route::get('/business/settings','BusinessController@settings');

Route::controller('/','HomeController');
Route::resource('/business','BusinessController');
Route::resource('/','UserStandardController');
Route::resource('/','UserBusinessController');
```

Basically:

- **HomeController** is used for loading the views for the standard user.
- **BusinessController** is used for loading the views for the business user.
- **UserStandardController** and **UserBusinessController** are used for the actions for those accounts, for example: login, logout, update settings, update profile, etc.

But the problem is when I try to load mysite.com/user/login, laravel says **"Method [login]" doesn't exists** and is obviously because in HomeController doesn't exists the login method but exists in UserStandardController... but I don't know how to do this.

I hope you can help me!

Comment: 3 controllers with `/` as the path... does anything actually work if it's not in the HomeController?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have `POST` route for `/user/login`, you need to have `Route::get` also.

Comment: Sorry for late, I solved my problem before you leave your answer but more or less, I used the same fix . Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a login method in UserStandardController class for this error to go away.

As /user/login is searching for a login method in UserStandardController.

I hope this helps.